# ADODB Multiple Databases

Tags: php, mysql, database, adodb

I am using adodb for my database operations and here i am facing a problem that i can't add tow or 3 databases in my script i am using 3 databases but its not working properly need help in this situation.

myadodb connection file:

```
<?php
include_once("/adodb/adodb.inc.php");
include_once("/adodb/adodb-exceptions.inc.php");
class ADb {
    function ADb()
    {
        global $dbserver;
        global $dbuser;
        global $dbpass;
        global $database;

        $dbuser = "";
        $dbpass = "";
        $dbserver = "";                
        $database = "";

        $this->conn1 = &ADONewConnection('mysql'); 
        $this->conn1->PConnect($dbserver, $dbuser, $dbpass, $database);
    }                   
    function query($sql)
    {
        try
        {
            $Result = $this->conn1->Execute($sql);
        }
        catch (exception $e)
        {
            echo $e->msg;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I have created 3 files for 3 databases connections

Comment: I discoverd the same problem. I happens only when you connect multiple dbs on the same host/ip.
In my case (for db on localhost) I could workarround this problem.
I connected my first db to `127.0.0.1`, my second to `127.0.0.2` ect.. But thats no real solution for this bug.

Answer (score 2):

This is a quick class that I made that should allow you to connect to 3 databases using adoDB:

```
class Data {
    private static $_dbOne = null;
    private static $_dbTwo = null;
    private static $_dbThree = null;

    protected function __construct() {
    }

    /**
     * This function returns the database connection object
     * @return Object Database Connection
     */
    public static function dbOne() {
        include_once(LIBRARY_PATH.'adodb5/adodb.inc.php');
        if (null === self::$_dbOne) {


            $_connOne = 'mysql://username:password@www.server.com/database';

            self::$_dbOne = &ADONewConnection($_connOne);
            if (self::$_dbOne==false) { die('Could not connect to the database.'); }

        }

        return self::$_dbOne;
    }

    /**
     * This function returns the database connection object
     * @return Object Database Connection
     */
    public static function dbTwo() {
        include_once(LIBRARY_PATH.'adodb5/adodb.inc.php');
        if (null === self::$_dbTwo) {


            $_connTwo = 'mysql://username:password@www.server.com/database';

            self::$_dbTwo = &ADONewConnection($_connTwo);
            if (self::$_dbTwo==false) { die('Could not connect to the database.'); }

        }

        return self::$_dbTwo;
    }

}

    /**
     * This function returns the database connection object
     * @return Object Database Connection
     */
    public static function dbThree() {
        include_once(LIBRARY_PATH.'adodb5/adodb.inc.php');
        if (null === self::$_dbThree) {


            $_connThree = 'mysql://username:password@www.server.com/database';

            self::$_dbThree = &ADONewConnection($_connThree);
            if (self::$_dbThree==false) { die('Could not connect to the database.'); }

        }

        return self::$_dbThree;
    }

}
```

Here is an example of how you would use this class:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM *";
$results1 = Data::dbOne()->Execute($sql);
$results2 = Data::dbTwo()->Execute($sql);
$results3 = Data::dbThree()->Execute($sql);
```

Comment: can i connect 3 databases in the same way?

Comment: Yes, I added an example of the third database above. It would be added the same way the first and second connection were added, buy creating a new function in the class that returns the connection object for a specific database. This is just one way to connect to multiple databases. There are several different ways that you can do this.